# Is there a faster alternative to getting a subset of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I'm currently working on some Python code where I'm trying to retrieve a subset of a DataFrame where the column value equals a certain value. I'm doing it like so:

```
for i in brands.index:
    current_brand = brands.get_value(i, 'Car Brand')
    my_dataframe_subset = my_dataframe[my_dataframe['Brand'] == current_brand]
```

This of course works in making the subset, but I'm doing this continuously in a loop, thousands of times. What I've found is that this is a huge bottleneck in my execution speed, but unfortunately the '`current_brand`' changes every iteration of the loop so I don't see another way. Is there a faster alternative to getting this subset that wouldn't cause such a huge delay?

Thanks

**EDIT**:
This is a more realistic example of what my code is doing. Obviously the data is gibberish, but I hope you get the idea:

```
------------------------
|Person | Car Brand |
|------------------------
|'dave' | 'Toyota'  |
|'mike' | 'Ford'    |
|'sally'| 'Ford'    |
|'doug' | 'BMW'     |
------------------------
my_list = []
for i in brands.index:
    current_person = brands.get_value(i, 'Person')
    current_brand = brands.get_value(i, 'Car Brand')
    my_dataframe_subset = my_dataframe[my_dataframe['Brand'] == current_brand] 

    for i_b in my_dataframe_subset.index:
        #do stuff with current_person and current_brand
        car_colour = my_dataframe_subset(i_b, 'Colour')
        car_speed = my_dataframe_subset(i_b, 'Speeds')
        my_dict = {'person': current_person, 'brand': current_brand, 'colour': car_colour, 'speed': car_speed}
        my_list.append(my_dict)
```

Comment: Can you add some data samples?

Comment: Specifically, does the `brands` dataframe contain less than the unique values in `my_dataframe`?

Comment: @jezrael Done, added

Comment: @PL200 - Can you explain more `#do stuff with current_person and current_brand` ?

Comment: @jezrael Sure, I've appended the OP. The data doesn't make a lot of sense, but you can hopefully see what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @PL200 - My answer was edited, please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with default inner join:

```
brands = pd.DataFrame({
        'Person': ['dave', 'mike', 'sall', 'doug'], 
        'Car Brand': ['Kia', 'Ford', 'Ford', 'BMW']
})

my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({
        'Brand':['Toyota','Toyota','BMW', 'BMW', 'BMW', 'Ford'],
         'Speeds':[40,50,20,10,30,40],
         'Colour':list('abcdef')
})
print (my_dataframe)
    Brand  Speeds Colour
0  Toyota      40      a
1  Toyota      50      b
2     BMW      20      c
3     BMW      10      d
4     BMW      30      e
5    Ford      40      f

d = {'Car Brand':'Brand'}
df = brands.rename(columns=d).merge(my_dataframe, on='Brand')
print (df)
  Person Brand  Speeds Colour
0   mike  Ford      40      f
1   sall  Ford      40      f
2   doug   BMW      20      c
3   doug   BMW      10      d
4   doug   BMW      30      e
```

If need list of dictionaries:

```
my_list = df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Comment: @PL200 - Can you add some data samples? Because not sure if understand.

Comment: Hi @jezarel, Added better example of code to OP, to show why I'm not sure this solution will work.

Comment: @PL200 - Waht return `print (my_dataframe.columns.tolist())` and `print (brands.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: Never mind, a mistake of my own. This solution works perfectly. Taken my execution time from ~10 minutes to about 5 seconds. Thanks!

Comment: @PL200 - Super ;)

Answer (score 1):

1) Iterate through all unique brands from the `brands` dataframe.

2) Filter rows in the `my_dataframe` dataframe that match the brand.

Depending on how you want to handle empty sets (i.e. when there is no `brand` in `my_dataframe` that matches the one from `brands`), you could simply group by `Brand` in `my_dataframe` as illustrated by both @jezrael and @chthonicdaemon.

```
for current_brand in brands['Car Brand'].unique():
    brand_df = my_dataframe[my_dataframe['Brand'] == current_brand]
    # Do stuff with filtered brand dataframe.
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with some sample data:

```
import pandas
brands = pandas.DataFrame({'Car Brand': ['Toyota', 'Honda']})
my_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame({'Brand': ['Toyota']*4 + ['Honda']*4, 'Value': [1]*8})
```

For the situation in this data, the `brands` dataframe contains only the unique values in the `my_dataframe.Brand` column. In this case you can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) directly:

```
for current_brand, my_dataframe_subset in my_dataframe.groupby('Brand'):
    # do stuff with subset
```

If there are less brands in `brands` than in  `my_dataframe`, you can filter them out:

```
dataset_for_brands = my_dataframe[my_dataframe.Brand.isin(brands['Car Brand'])]
for current_brand, my_dataframe_subset in dataset_for_brands.groupby('Brand'):
    # do stuff with subset
```

It might even be possible for you to avoid the loop altogether if you are calculating aggregates for the groups, so let's say you want the average value per group, you can do

```
my_dataframe.groupby('Brand').Value.mean()
```

and get the answer directly:

```
Brand
Honda     1
Toyota    1
```

Comment: @jezrael Could you be more specific?

Comment: Because it seems there are `2` DataFrames.

Comment: My post was made before OP added the second dataframe.